# SQL- convert wide to long table with 3 special rules

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
Individual   Organisation   Time1        Time2        T_diff   Time1_original
111          2              01-04-2020   01-05-2020   1        01-04-2020
111          2              01-05-2020   01-04-2021   11       01-04-2020
122          2              01-04-2020   01-01-2021   9        01-04-2020
122          3              01-01-2021                         01-01-2021
```

I would like to convert it to the following one:

```
Individual      Organisation      Times      
111             2                 01-04-2020 (Time1-line1)
111             2                 01-04-2021 (Time2-line2)
122             2                 01-04-2020 (Time1)
122             2                 01-01-2021 (Time2)
122             3                 01-01-2021 (Time1)
```

3 conditions:

For each `Individual-Organisation`,

If (`T_diff <= 3` OR `T_diff IS NULL`) AND `Time1 EQUAL TO Time1_original` bring `Time1`

If `T_diff > 3` & `Time1 NOT EQUAL TO Time1_original` bring `Time2`

If `T_diff > 3` & `Time1 EQUAL TO Time1_original` bring `Time1` & `Time2`

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: You need to TAG your RDBMS

Comment: I've included it now, thanks @Stu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements involve some *pivoting* of columns into rows.

Your column names are a little misleading having *dates* not *times*; Ideally you would specify dates as YYYYMMDD, it looks like you are using DD-MM-YYYY.

A *lateral join* makes this easy, in SQL Server this is done using *apply()*.

You've also *edited your sample data* after posting your question, I worked with the data you originally posted.

```
with timeywimey as (
    select * 
    from t
    cross apply(values
      (case 
        when (t_diff <= 3 or t_diff is null) and time1 = time1_original then time1 
        else 
          case when t_diff > 3 then
            iif(time1 = time1_original, time1, time2)
          end 
        end
        ),
        (case when t_diff > 3 and time1 = time1_original then time2 end)
    )v(Times)
)
select individual, organisation, times 
from timeywimey 
where Times is not null;
```

See [Demo DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2bf999c86e7d5f9bb8c96aa70d6fcf61)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stu, it should say "Times" instead of "times" line 16, right? Also "if" and not "iif" line 9 right? I know I said I am using SQL Server because I usually follow that format and works. But it is not working for me this time. I am using HiveQL, sorry for the confusion, usually works, but it is not working this time.It might be the cross apply.

Comment: Sorry for editing my data, I thought these examples would be enough, that's why I changed it. My times are indeed dates, and I am using YYYYMMDD. I will update my question.

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues The solution is for SQL Server, the RDBMS you stated. I have no knowledge of HiveQL - the `iif` is an "inline if" - in some products eg MySql it *is* just `if`, so try that; it's just a more compact version of *case* so if it doesn't work you can replace it with a case expression; as you can see from the demo Fiddle, it does work - in SQL Server! It shouldn't matter `times vs Times` - SQL is a case insensitive language.

Comment: Yes, your solution works in SQL Server, thanks for your help @Stu. I only avoided mentioning HiveQL because no ones seems to know about this language, so I thought I would never get any responses. Unfortunately this solution does not translate to HiveQL.

Comment: so that's not unexpected to be honest, each RDBMS has its own dialect for some features - you must have been lucky that other answers for SQL Server have worked. You can probably take the principle though and translate it easily enough, eg when I Google I see that numerous questions about using SQL Server `Apply` in HiveQL exist.

Comment: If it proves not to be portable you can basically do the same by splitting the cross apply() out to be two *unioned* queries.

Comment: I don't think it is, unfortunately. How would you do that, two unioned queries instead of cross apply? I tried to create a extra variable using the logic of case, but it does not work because I also need to do some sort of wide to long reshape to create the new rows.

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues I have refactored the query to be a union, see other answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stu, This query works like a charm as i was facing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer as it's easy to convert my other answer to a more ANSI-compliant version using a *union*. This is much more likely to work in HiveQL, I would think.

```
with timey as (
  select *, 
    case 
      when (T_diff <= 3 or T_diff is null) and Time1 = Time1_original then Time1 
      else 
        case when T_diff > 3 then
          case when Time1 = Time1_original then Time1 else Time2 end
        end 
      end as Times
    from t
  union all
  select *, 
    case when T_diff > 3 and Time1 = Time1_original then Time2 end as Times
  from t
)
select Individual, Organisation, Times
from timey
where Times is not null
order by Individual, Times;
```

[DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5819c01c3fcee501bd9da3c5f20cb44e)

Comment: Awesome, that's a win then.